# Declaring a set of Variables as a Function of Another Variable

Tags: vba, excel, variables

I'm attempting to assign strings based on column entries of which the amount changes (may be 15-40 entries depending on the day), then open URLs by adding the strings to a fixed beginning of the URL. My issue is the assignment of the variables. My code is as follows:

```
'LOOP 1:
    'Table Entries

Dim RowCount As Integer


    Sheets("Table").Select
    Sheets("Table").Range("A2").Select
    Do While True
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
            RowCount = ActiveCell.Row
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

RowCount = RowCount - 2

'LOOP 2:
    'Assign IDs and URLs

Dim ID(1 To RowCount) As Variant
Dim URL(1 To RowCount) As String
Dim i1 As Integer

    For i1 = 1 To RowCount
        ID(i1) = Sheets("Table").Range("A" + CStr(i + 1)).Value
        URL(i1) = "--Redacted--" + CStr(URL(i1))
    Next i1
```

The issue is declaring the ID and URL variables as a function of RowCount. I'm sure there is another way to declare these, but my lack of experience is showing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You say you have an issue but what is it?

Comment: "My issue is the assignment of the variables"  --- what variables? This is unclear.

Comment: I recommend to read: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) to make your code faster, shorter and more reliable.

Comment: ID() only get filled with value of cell A1 ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you have found:

```
Sub ThisFails()
    RowCount = 9
    Dim URL(1 To RowCount) As String
End Sub
```

does not work, but:

```
Sub ThisWorks()
    Dim URL() As String
    RowCount = 9
    ReDim URL(1 To RowCount)
End Sub
```

will work

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the thing you're trying to accomplish; an array with ["--redacted--" + string]
you could try:

```
Sub Try()
Dim URL() As String
With Sheets("Table")
    URL = Split("--Redacted--" & Join(Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown))), "|--Redacted--"), "|")
End With

End Sub
```

No need to loop or find an empty cell for your RowCount